# Swift Dynamic Cast Failure

Tags: json, swift, xcode6

i am trying to get the ID for a user and my script keeps failing:

```
    func getUserID(users:NSString){
    var username:NSString = "abcd"
    println(username)
    if ( username.isEqualToString("")) {

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Failed to find user"
        alertView.message = "Please try logging in and out."
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {

    var post:NSString = "username=\(username)"

    NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://turbo-tires-21-188007.euw1.nitrousbox.com/jsonGetUserID.php")!

    var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary


            let idusers:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as NSInteger

        }
    }
    }

}
```

and the error output is as following:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x111199620:  pushq  %rbp
0x111199621:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x111199624:  pushq  %rbx
0x111199625:  pushq  %rax
0x111199626:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x111199629:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x11119962c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x11119962e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x111199631:  je     0x11119964c               ;
swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x111199633:  movq   0x82756(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x11119963a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x11119963d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x111199640:  callq  0x11119c1ca               ; symbol stub for:  
objc_msgSend
0x111199645:  testb  %al, %al
0x111199647:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x11119964a:  je     0x111199653               ; 
swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x11119964c:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x111199650:  popq   %rbx
0x111199651:  popq   %rbp
0x111199652:  retq   
0x111199653:  leaq   0xcdc8(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x11119965a:  movq   %rax, 0x8ae57(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x111199661:  int3   
0x111199662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I have tried alot of different ways thinking it was the format of string but nothing has worked so far.

```
getUserID("abcd");
```

This is how I call the method. This error crashes the app and asside from the error above, I get (lldb) in the consoled. Any help would be great.

UPDATE: I have narrowed down the error:

```
let idusers:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as NSInteger
```

SOLVED:
the problem was the number in the json is a string so I used NSString and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `jsonData` is an NSDictionary, it can only contain objects. NSInteger is not an object, it is a typecast for `int` or `long`. I assume your value is actually an NSNumber, so your cast should be:

```
let idusers: = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as NSNumber
```

In your case, the value turned out to be a string:

```
let idusers: = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as String
```

Comment: let idusers:NSNumber = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as NSNumber seems to be the same error.

Comment: NSInteger does work the problem was the number in the json is a string so I used NSString and it works.

Comment: Ah well, I assumed is was actually a number, but yeah if it's a string you should use `NSString` ;).

Comment: You post was just about right, It lead me to follow the data and look at the format and BAM there we go. If you want to adjust your comment to specify the formatting. Very glad to have it working, Something like that took me nearly an hour to solve xD